# What should be the logic behind parsing a file containing (HTTP and data) and (ETag and data) and (HTTP,ETag and data)

Tags: c, linux, http, etag

I am trying to parse a file containing multiple header and data so that header part

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, private
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Sat, 15 Nov 2008 16:00:00 GMT
P3P: policyref="http://cdn.adnxs.com/w3c/policy/p3p.xml", CP="NOI DSP COR ADM PSAo PSDo OURo SAMo UNRo OTRo BUS COM NAV DEM STA PRE"
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Location: http://ib.adnxs.com/tt?id=868557&size=728x90&referrer=facebook.com
Date: Thu, 31 Jan 2013 05:49:01 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

can be written into a separate file(.header) and the content after this header information can be stored in a data file(.data).

But problem comes when some header part contains ETag field and 
      the header where only ETag is written in place on HTTP.

What should be the logic so that it can be parsed??

Comment: ETag: "2790fa9a82fdcd1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Age: 2498
Date: Thu, 31 Jan 2013 05:49:01 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 28 Jan 2013 18:09:25 GMT
Content-Length: 2432
Connection: keep-alive

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=60,stale-while
Content-Length: 44
Content-Type: image/gif
Date: Thu, 31 Jan 2013 05:48:31 GMT
Etag: "YM:1:f5c25396-26ac-4e57-a715-66f32aa0289b0004cee17fc45c58"
Expires: Thu, 31 Jan 2013 05:49:31 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 19 Nov 2012 23:30:13 GMT
Server: ATS/3.2.0
Via: HTTP/1.1 web1.use5.mobstor.ac4.yahoo.com YahooTrafficServer/3.0.1 (UFF), http/1.0 l1.ycs.dxs.yahoo.com (ApacheTrafficServer/3.2.0)
x-ysws-request-id: 59942e6b-4ee2-ac59-d575368bcec9
x-ysws-visited-replicas: gops.use5.mobstor.vip.ac4.yahoo.com
Age: 31
Connection: keep-alive

Comment: I don't understand the statement "But problem comes when some header part contains ETag field and the header where only ETag is written in place on HTTP." -- give an example and state what the problem is.

Comment: I have a file in which content is available in this fashion:-          HTTP 302 Found.......content type,content length>>>>then after \n\r\n\r>>>>data of a .pdf of jpeg file written in text>>>>ETag: "2790fa9a82fdcd1:0" .........content type,content length>>>>then after \n\r\n\r>>>>>>some data like .pdf or .jpeg file written in text>>>>>In the next step,itcan be HTTP or ETag.But in some cases "HTTP......ETag:.."2790fa9a82fdcd1:0"..Content type,content length" contains ETag also

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you're talking about.

Can you post a sample URI?